# Running long process in WCF Service

Tags: c#, wcf, service, queue

I have a WCF service which configure to be one way and below Service configuration:
[Service Behaviour(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]

This is what the service does:-
First sync files from source control then parse the files next reconstruct contents in another format and rewrite the files out. Finally check into source control again.

It works fine when only 1 call being invoke. But when there are multiple calls invoke at the same time, they will all stuck at the sync part example caller A contains file but caller B no file found. If this happen subsequent call will failed until Application pool get restarted.

There is no error return from the service is just got lost somewhere and process stuck in the middle.

Is it advisable to implement a long process like above with syncing files from source control in wcf service or invoking an exe each time service call or should I put it in queue mechanism and let the queue to manage the processing?

Thanks.